# find the interval of a given date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm struggling with date objects in python.

I have the following data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
# date retrieved from a list
ini =  [u'2016-01-01']
# transform the ini in a readable string
ini2 = ', '.join(map(str, ini))
# transform the string a date object
date_1 = datetime.strptime(ini2, "%Y-%m-%d")
# number that is the length of the date
l = 365.0
# adding l to ini2
final = date_1 + timedelta(days = l)
```

Now I'd need to *split* the whole interval (that is the period from `date_1` to `final`) by an input number (e.g. ts = 4) and, given another input date (e.g. `new_date = u'2016-05-19'`) check in which *interval* it is (in the example 19th of May is in t2 = 2).

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Thanks
I tried different approaches but none seems the right one.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make any sense to me, but whatever it is you're trying to do, I think you might benefit from working with epoch time, which would make the math fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def which_interval(date0, delta, date1, n_intervals):
    date0 = datetime.strptime(date0, '%Y-%m-%d')
    delta = timedelta(days = delta)
    date1 = datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d')
    delta1 = date1 - date0
    quadrile = int(((float(delta1.days) / delta.days) * n_intervals))
    return quadrile


# Example: figure out which quarter August 1st is in
interval = which_interval(
    '2016-01-01',
    366,
    '2016-08-01',
    4)
print '2016-08-01 is in interval %d, Q%d'%(interval, interval+1)
```

Note that this function uses python indices  so it will start at quarter 0 and end at quarter 3. If you want 1-based indices (so the answer will be 1, 2, 3, or 4) you would want to add 1 to the result.

Comment: hi.. I'm using your function with this variables but the output is not the rigth one (19th of May should be in the 2nd quarter while the function output is 1). ini = '2016-01-01', fin ='2016-05-19', length = 365, ts = 4. Thanks

Comment: this function uses python indices (much like my solution) so it will start at quarter 0 and end at quarter 3 (unless it is equal to the end date) so you would want to just add 1 to the result.

Comment: Uh, sorry.. I get it now.. :)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - I just stole your explanation. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Robᵩ, you did not steal it you implemented it into your answer which is absolutely fine.  I'd also like to point out you can completely avoid float division if you do the multiplication first: `quadrile = n_intervals * delta1.days // delta.days` or if the delta could be more precise then days: `n_intervals * delta1.total_seconds() // delta.total_seconds()`

Comment: it is also still important to note that the end date would return 4 (be in quarter 5) with this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

the `timedelta` object supports division, so use floor division by a `step` and you will get an interval in `range(ts)`

```
new_date = datetime.strptime(u'2016-05-19', "%Y-%m-%d")

ts = 4
step = timedelta(days=l)/ts #divide by the number of steps

interval = (new_date - date_1)//step #get the number this interval is in
```

so for `date_1 <= new_date < date_1 + step` interval will be 0, for `date_1+step<=new_date < date_1 + step*2` interval will be 1, etc.

This of course is using python style indices so to get the number starting from 1, add one:

```
 interval = (new_date - date_1)//step + 1
```

EDIT: the functionality to divide timedelta objects was only added in python3, you would need to use the `.total_seconds()` method to do the calculation in python 2:

```
step = timedelta(days=l).total_seconds()/ts #divide by inteval

interval =  (new_date - date_1).total_seconds()//step
```

Comment: Hi.. I get the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta' has this something to do with the data input?

Comment: yes sorry, I just tested this in python2.7 and it seems support for this operation was only added in python 3, currently looking for the code to implement the actual function...

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate this using the seconds total of the intervals.

```
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

l = 365.0
factor = 4
date_1 = datetime.strptime('2016-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
lookup_dt = datetime.strptime('2016-12-01', "%Y-%m-%d")

def get_interval_num(factor, start_dt, td, lookup_dt):
    final = start_dt + td
    interval = (final - start_dt).total_seconds()
    subinterval = interval / factor
    interval_2 = (lookup_dt - start_dt).total_seconds()
    return int(math.ceil(interval_2 / subinterval))

num = get_interval_num(
    factor=factor,
    start_dt=date_1,
    td= timedelta(days=l),
    lookup_dt=lookup_dt
)
print("The interval number is: %s" % num)
```

Output would be:

```
The interval number is: 4
```

EDIT: clearified variable naming, extended code snippet

Comment: HI.. I get this error by copy and pasting your code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 4, in get_interval_num
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: factor has to be > 1, everything else wouldn't make sense, right?